# What is the use of open properties in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have been learning Kotlin and have come across the concept of open properties. Coming from C++, the concept of "open" makes sense, and extending that logic to properties does as well. However, I can't think of any case where an `open val`/`var` is actually necessary or useful. I understand when they make sense for interfaces, but not concrete classes. Furthermore, overriding getters/setters makes sense, but not redefining the property with a new backing field. For example, say you have this kind of class structure:

```
open class Foo {
    open var str = "Hello"
}


class Bar : Foo() {
    override var str = "world" 

    init {
        println(str)
        println(super.str) // Shows that Bar actually contains "hello" and "world"
    }
}
```

To me, it would seem to be a far better design to make Foo take `str` as a constructor argument, for instance:

```
open class Foo(var str = "Hello") // Maybe make a secondary constructor

class Bar : Foo("world") // Bar has only 1 string
```

This is both more concise, and seems to often be a better design. This is also the way it tends to be done in C++, so maybe I just don't see the benefit of the other way. The only possible time I can see overriding a `val`/`var` with a new one is if it for some reason needs to use `super`'s value, like in

```
    override val foo = super.foo * 2
```

Which still seems pretty contrived.

When have you found this useful? Does it allow for greater efficiency or ease of use?

Comment: It is the opposite of `final`, in C++ it's like `virtual`

Comment: I understand that, but I like I said in the post I don't see where it is useful

Comment: Your comment says “// Bar now has 2 strings in it”, but it doesn't.  (In fact, because string constants are shared, there's only one single `String` instance containing "world", shared by all `Bar` instances.)  Your example of passing the string into a constructor is great where the string can vary; but the hard-coded version could also make sense where the string must be the same across all instances of a particular class.

Comment: I thought Bar would contain one reference to "hello" and one to "world" (with "hello" being stored in super.str). Is that not the case? I tested out using `str` and `super.str` in an `init` block, and both existed, so I assumed that `Bar` contains references to both strings

Comment: "overriding getters/setters makes sense" Well, there you go. That's the primary use for `open val`, and there's no reason to ban "redefining the property with a new backing field".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open` fields let you re-define getter and setter methods. It's practically pointless if you just return constants. However altering getter / setter behavior has (infinite) potential, so I'll just throw some ideas:

```
// propagate get/set to parent class
class Bar : Foo() {
    override var str
        get() = super.str.toUpperCase()
        set(value) {
            super.str = value
        }
}

// creates a backing field for this property
class Bar : Foo() {
    override var str = "World"
        get() = field.toLowerCase()
        // no need to define custom set if we don't need it in this case
        // set(value) { field = value }
}

// instead of writing custom get/set, you can also use delegates
class Bar : Foo() {
    override var str by Delegates.observable("world"){ prop, old, new ->
        println("${prop.name} changed from $old to $new")
    }
}
```